# The difference between rational map and polynomial map between affine varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Could any body show me the difference between rational map and polynomial map between affine varieties? What are the relations between them? 
Please feel freely answering my question since I am a newbie to algebraic geometry and I am not talented.

Thank for reading my question.

Comment: A rational map is one given by a quotient of polynomials, while a polynomial map is one given by a polynomial.

Comment: Thank Becker for that. I got a sensation about something deeper, but I could not find or say it concretely.

Comment: For an example, consider maps between the variety in affine 2-space defined by $x=0$ and that defined by $xy-1=0$.